# Correct version of pasuk about wisdom

Tags: sources-mekorot, quotations

An old teacher of mine is about to turn 90 and I'm trying to locate a pasuk, which, I think, says: "Treasure the words of a wise man for they are..." or "Heed the words of a wise man, for they are more [valuable?] than [treasure?]". I'm beginning to wonder whether I've confused one or more pesukim.  Any ideas?

Comment: DanH, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Mishlei 25:12](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2825.htm#12):

> יב  נֶזֶם זָהָב, וַחֲלִי-כָתֶם--    מוֹכִיחַ חָכָם, עַל-אֹזֶן שֹׁמָעַת.
>   12 As an ear-ring of gold, and an ornament of fine gold, so is a wise reprover upon an obedient ear.

In other words, the rebuke of a wise man is gold to those who will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This smacks of *Mishlei* thematically. Perhaps you're thinking of [22](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%9B%D7%91):17-18, in terms of wisdom being *quid pro quo*, although there is no treasure here:

> הַט אָזְנְךָ וּשְׁמַע דִּבְרֵי חֲכָמִים וְלִבְּךָ תָּשִׁית לְדַעְתִּי. כִּי נָעִים כִּי תִשְׁמְרֵם בְּבִטְנֶךָ יִכֹּנוּ יַחְדָּו עַל שְׂפָתֶיךָ

[JPS](http://mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et2822.htm):

> Incline thine ear, and hear the words of the wise, and apply thy heart unto my knowledge.
>   For it is a pleasant thing if thou keep them within thee; let them be established altogether upon thy lips.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you were thinking of the first half of [Ecclesiastes 10:12](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3110.htm#12):

> דִּבְרֵי פִי-חָכָם, חֵן; וְשִׂפְתוֹת כְּסִיל, תְּבַלְּעֶנּוּ.‏
>   The words of a wise man's mouth are gracious; but the lips of a fool will swallow up himself.